# How to have exactly same space in rotating text vertically as we have when the text is horizontal

Tags: html, css, svg, vertical-text

I am trying to get text to display vertically in svg using double rotation. I want to rotate each character zero degree and all the characters aligned vertically.Lets say the original svg is:

```html
   <svg x="351" y="631" width="400" height="40" lines="1" type="textWrap" textWrap="false" name="VERTICAL TEXT TEST"><text x="0" y="40" font-family="Oswald Medium" letter-spacing="1.4" font-size="35px" characterWidth="0" textLength="none" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" fill="black" text-anchor="start"  >VERTICAL TEXT TEST</text></svg>
```

**RESULT:**

```html
    <svg x="351" y="631" width="400" height="40" lines="1" type="textWrap" textWrap="false" name="VERTICAL TEXT TEST"><text x="0" y="40" font-family="Oswald Medium" letter-spacing="1.4" font-size="35px" characterWidth="0" textLength="none" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" fill="black" text-anchor="start">VERTICAL TEXT TEST</text></svg>
```

Now to vertically rotate I tried this approach:

1.Swapping of height and width of svg
2. double rotate by 90deg using rotation and transform function

Here is the code for that:

```html
    <svg x="351" y="631" width="40" height="400" lines="1" type="textWrap" textWrap="false" name="VERTICAL TEXT TEST"><text x="0" y="40" font-family="Oswald Medium" letter-spacing="1.4" font-size="35px" characterWidth="0" textLength="none" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" fill="black" text-anchor="start" transform="rotate(90 0 40)" rotate="-90" >VERTICAL TEXT TEST</text></svg>
```

RESULT :

[image: RESULT AFTER VERTICAL ROTATION]

So, as evident in the image that the spaces between letters are not being handled properly. So how to implement that the spaces get itself handled dynamically. Basically, my requirement is if someone clicks on a button to rotate the text vertically, it should be shown in top to bottom direction with the original spaces an it was in horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

You should use text-orientation and writing-mode to get vertical text.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
text {
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%"><text x="100" y="0" font-family="Oswald Medium" font-size="35px" fill="black" writing-mode="vertical-lr" text-anchor="start">VERTICAL TEXT TEST</text></svg>
```

Comment: I only want to do this using svg attributes. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Unfortunately text-orientation is not a mapped CSS attribute. You could ask the w3c to add it as a mapped attribute, I'd be supportive of implementing it in Firefox if that was the case.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , but I was looking for a quick fix solution and that too using SVG attributes

Comment: Many SVG attributes are simply CSS properties though. There really is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `letter-spacing` it Will affect vertical spacing in your case because of rotation

```html
<svg x="351" y="631" width="40" height="620" lines="1" type="textWrap" textWrap="false" name="VERTICAL TEXT TEST"><text x="0" y="40" font-family="Oswald Medium" letter-spacing="13" font-size="35px" characterWidth="0" textLength="none" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" fill="black" text-anchor="start" transform="rotate(90 0 40)" rotate="-90" >VERTICAL TEXT TEST</text></svg>
```

Comment: Yes ,you are right  we can use letter-spacing but how will I determine letter-spacing dynamically?